# django global var

Tags: python, django

Всем, привет! Есть небольшой код:

```
           def login_view(request):
                if request.user.is_authenticated():
                    return redirect(reverse('search'))
                if request.method == 'POST':
                    username = request.POST['username']
                    password = request.POST['password']
                    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                    if user is not None:
                        if user.is_active:
                            login(request, user)
                            global bill
                            bill = URFAClient("10.0.1.7", 11758, username, password)
                            messages.success(request, "account ok")
                        else:
                            messages.warning(request, "account disable")
                    else:
                        return redirect(reverse('login'))
                return auth_views.login(request, 'accounts/login.html')
```

Как сделать чтобы глобальная переменная bill была видна в других app при import?

Comment: Думаю просто стоит объявить данную переменную на уровне модуля

Comment: А можете описать для чего это нужно? Выгядит как ошибка проектирования.